# Vertical image slider with jquery

Tags: list, jquery

I have a ticker news with vertical sliding. I need to slide both images and text along with it, which is coming from a single list.

How to give the image source in this jquery code? The image is a column name from an announcement list.
The code below is the jquery I have used for vertical scrolling ticker with only text.

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
var soapEnv ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                     <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>Ticker</listName> \
                        <viewFields> \
                            <ViewFields> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Title'/>\
                               <FieldRef Name='Body'/> \ 
                               <FieldRef Name='Link'/> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Image'/> \
                           </ViewFields> \
                        </viewFields> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>"; 

        $.ajax({
            url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: Result,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    }); 
tickmectr = 1;
function tick(){
if (tickmectr)
    $('#news li:first').slideUp( function () {
$(this).appendTo($('#news')).slideDown(); });
}


    function Result(xData, status) {
$("#news").html('');
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(


function() 
{
    var imageURL = ($(this).attr("ows_Image")).split(",")[0];
    var bodyURL = ($(this).attr("ows_Body")).split(",")[0];

    var linkticker = ($(this).attr("ows_Link"));
    var liHtml = "<li> <font color=blue > <b>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "<br>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") +  "</font></b> </li>";

    if ( linkticker )
    var liHtml = "<li> <font color=blue > <b>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</b></font> <div><tr align='top'>" + 
                            "<td><img src='" + imageURL + "'><br></td> <a href='" + linkticker  + "'>" + bodyURL +  "</a>" +
                           "</tr></div></li>";


        $("#news").append(liHtml);
    });

setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
} 
function tickme(tick)
{
    tickmectr=tick
}
 </script><style>
 UL#news {
POSITION: relative; MARGIN: 0px auto; WIDTH: 110px; BACKGROUND: #fff; HEIGHT: 170px
 }
 UL#news LI {
POSITION: relative; MARGIN: 0px; WIDTH: 150px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 170px
}</style><ul id="news" onmouseover="tickme(0)" onmouseout="tickme(1)"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
   <script type="text/javascript">




$(document).ready(function() {   
var soapEnv ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>New Hire</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title'/>\
                           <FieldRef Name='Body'/> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Link'/> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Image'/> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>"; 

    $.ajax({
        url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: Result,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}); 
tickmectr = 1;
function tick(){
    if (tickmectr)
$('#news li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#news')).slideDown(); });
}


function Result(xData, status) {
    $("#news").html('');
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(

function() 
{
 var imageURL = ($(this).attr("ows_Image")).split(",")[0];
 var bodyURL = ($(this).attr("ows_Body")).split(",")[0];

    var linkticker = ($(this).attr("ows_Link"));
    var liHtml = "<li> <font color=blue > <b>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "<br>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") +  "</font></b> </li>";

    if ( linkticker )
    var liHtml = "<li> <font color=blue > <b>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</b></font> <div><tr align='top'>" + 
                            "<td><img src='" + imageURL + "'><br></td> <a href='" + linkticker  + "'>" + bodyURL +  "</a>" +
                           "</tr></div></li>";


        $("#news").append(liHtml);
    });

    setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
} 
 function tickme(tick)
 {
     tickmectr=tick
 }
     </script>
    <style>
 UL#news {
POSITION: relative; MARGIN: 0px auto; WIDTH: 110px; BACKGROUND: #fff; HEIGHT: 170px
  }
  UL#news LI {
POSITION: relative; MARGIN: 0px; WIDTH: 150px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 170px
 }
 </style>
  <ul id="news" onmouseover="tickme(0)" onmouseout="tickme(1)"></ul>
```